# Can port forwarding be done with IPsec?

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, ipsec

If i understand correctly, SSH tunnelling allows for the binding of a local port to a remote port through a SSH server. If I'm right, could something similar be done with IPsec?

Comment: Port forwarding isn't *necessary* with IPSec because IPSec is at the IP layer.  Assuming no firewall interference, *all* ports for *all* protocols essentially "just work" through an IPSec tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an IPSec VPN sends traffic through IPSec and split tunnelling is where you only send some of your data through the vpn.

I've not played with split tunnelling much and I've only seen it configured to split traffic by destination IP, but I'm sure there will be ways to do it by tcp/udp port. Can't really point you to more information without knowing what OS you want to do this on.

Hope this helps.